# I need the LaTex code for thist figure. I have tried many times but are some issues

Tags: tables, framed

[image]

here is the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

% Define a new command for drawing rectangles with specified width and height
\newcommand{\myrectangle}[6]{\draw (0,0) rectangle (#1,#2);}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|}
\hline
Your content here \\
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \myrectangle{4}{4} % First box
    \node[align=left, anchor=north] at (0.5,0.9) {Text 1}; % Text inside first box
    
    \begin{scope}[shift={(0.2,2)}] % Shift for the first nested box
        \myrectangle{3.5}{2} % First nested box
        \node[align=left, anchor=north] at (0.3,0.4) {Nested 1a}; % Text inside first nested box
    \end{scope}
    
    \begin{scope}[shift={(0.2,0.1)}] % Shift for the second nested box
        \myrectangle{2}{2} % Second nested box
        \node[align=left, anchor=north] at (0.3,0.4) {Nested 1b}; % Text inside second nested box
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \myrectangle{4}{4} % Second box
    \node[align=left, anchor=north] at (0.5,0.9) {Text 2}; % Text inside second box
    
    \begin{scope}[shift={(0.2,0.5)}] % Shift for the first nested box
        \myrectangle{0.6}{0.4} % First nested box
        \node[align=left, anchor=north] at (0.3,0.4) {Nested 2a}; % Text inside first nested box
    \end{scope}
    
    \begin{scope}[shift={(0.2,0.1)}] % Shift for the second nested box
        \myrectangle{0.6}{0.4} % Second nested box
        \node[align=left, anchor=north] at (0.3,0.4) {Nested 2b}; % Text inside second nested box
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \myrectangle{4}{4} % Third box
    \node[align=left, anchor=north] at (0.5,0.9) {Text 3}; % Text inside third box
    
    \begin{scope}[shift={(0.2,0.5)}] % Shift for the first nested box
        \myrectangle{0.6}{0.4} % First nested box
        \node[align=left, anchor=north] at (0.3,0.4) {Nested 3a}; % Text inside first nested box
    \end{scope}
    
    \begin{scope}[shift={(0.2,0.1)}] % Shift for the second nested box
        \myrectangle{0.6}{0.4} % Second nested box
        \node[align=left, anchor=north] at (0.3,0.4) {Nested 3b}; % Text inside second nested box
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: result]
Can someone help me writing code for this figure? thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  "help me writing code" is not usually well received.  Since you have tried many times, it would be helpful if you posted the code that you think comes closest to your desired outcome.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You might be able to do it just using `\fbox`, `\parbox` and color or xcolor.

Comment: https://www.overleaf.com/2313353174scbbxpjhkdph#934749

Comment: take a look at `tcolorbox` section 21 Library `poster`

Answer (score 0):

I have made it

```
\fcolorbox{myorange}{white}{%
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\vspace{0.2cm}
    \begin{Large}
    \textbf{\textit{\color{myorange}Block 0.22-Make, Say and Write 2-digit numbers}}
    \end{Large}
    \vspace{0.2cm}
    \begin{center}
        \fcolorbox{titlebg}{white}{%
            \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
            \vspace{0.2cm}
            \begin{large}
            \color{myorange}\textbf{\textit{Session 0.22 A}}
            \end{large}
                \raggedright % Align text to the left
                \fbox{%
                    \parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}{%
                        \raggedright
                        \vspace{0.2cm}
                        \color{titlebg}\textit{\textbf{Daily Review \& Quick Teach (DRQT)}}
                        \vspace{1cm}
                    }%
                }\\[1ex]
                \fbox{%
                    \parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}{%
                        \raggedright
                        \color{titlebg}\textit{\textbf{Explicit Lesson:}}\\
                        \vspace{1.48cm}
                        \color{titlebg}\textit{Topic Make, Say and write 2-digit numbers}
                        \vspace{0.5cm}
                        
                    }%
                }
            \end{minipage}%
        }
        \hfill
        \fcolorbox{titlebg}{white}{%
            \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
            \vspace{0.2cm}
            \begin{large}
            \color{myorange}\textbf{\textit{Session 0.22 B}}
            \end{large}
                \raggedright % Align text to the left
                \fbox{%
                    \parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}{%
                        \raggedright
                        \vspace{0.2cm}
                        \color{titlebg}\textit{Daily Review \& Quick Teach (DRQT)}
                        \vspace{1cm}
                    }%
                }\\[1ex]
                \fcolorbox{darkgreen}{white}{%
                    \parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}{%
                        \raggedright
                        \color{darkgreen}\textit{\textbf{Measurement and Geometry or Probability and Statistics (MGPS) Outline:}}\\
                        \vspace{0.5cm}
                        \color{darkgreen}\textit{Topic: Today, Yesterday and Tomorro}      
                        \vspace{0.52cm}
                    }%
                }
            \end{minipage}%
        }
        \hfill
        \fcolorbox{titlebg}{white}{%
            \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
            \vspace{0.2cm}
            \begin{large}
            \color{myorange}\textbf{\textit{Session 0.22 C}}
            \end{large}
                \raggedright % Align text to the left
                \fbox{%
                    \parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}{%
                        \raggedright
                        \vspace{0.2cm}
                        \color{titlebg}\textit{Daily Review \& Quick Teach (DRQT)}
                        \vspace{1cm}
                    }%
                }\\[1ex]
                \fbox{%
                    \parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}{%
                        \raggedright
                    \color{titlebg}\textit{\textbf{Consolidation Lesson:}}\\
                        \vspace{1.48cm}
                        \color{titlebg}\textit{Topic Make, Say and write 2-digit numbers}
                        \vspace{0.5cm}
                    }%
                }
            \end{minipage}%
        }
    \end{center}
\end{minipage}%
}
```

Comment: Very good. However, your answer will be more valuable for future readers if you make it compilable, I.e. add what's missing, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with end{document}`. Thank you